# Pass prop via onClick Handler to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the simplified version of two components I have. Whenever I click on the InviteButton I want the Overlay inside the InviteButton to be visible, basically have the prop `show={true}`.  Unfortunately I struggle how to do it properly. Thanks for reading or even helping me out with this.

```
----file1----
import React, {useState } from 'react'

function ComponentOne () {
          return(
             <InviteButton>
                type="submit"
                onClick={() => {
                      setOpen(true);
                }}
                className="float-end"
                size="lg"
              >
                     {messages.send}
              </InviteButton>

)}


-----file2----
function InviteButton({onClick, open}) {
return(
   <Overlay show={open}>Overlay here </Overlay>

)}
InviteButton.defaultProps = {open:false, onClick:null}
```

Comment: You are missing `open prop` inside your `InviteButton`; 
```<InviteButton open={open}>...<InviteButton/>```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code snippet has some errors.
How are you using the useState hook in ComponentOne?

As a first suggestion, I would start with setting the prop `open` equal to a state variable.

```
function ComponentOne () {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  return(
    <InviteButton
       type="submit"
       onClick={setIsOpen(true)}
       open={isOpen}
       className="float-end"
       size="lg"
     >
       {messages.send}
     </InviteButton>
)}
```

As a next step, you should accept all these props on `InviteButton`, not just `open` and `onClick`